# Positive operators given by kernels

Tags: functional-analysis, markov-process

I am wondering about a proof or reference to the following claim by Getoor;
Let $(E,\mathscr E)$ and $(F,\mathscr F)$ be two measurable spaces. A (positive) {kernel} from $(F,\mathscr F)$ to $(E,\mathscr E)$ is a map
$$k: F\times \mathscr E \to [0,\infty],\quad (x,E)\mapsto k(x,E)$$
such that $x\mapsto K(x,A)$ is $\mathscr F$ measurable for each fixed $A\in \mathscr E$ and $A\mapsto k(x,A)$ is a measure on $(E,\mathscr E)$ for each fixed $x\in F$. If $k$ is a bounded kernel from $(F,\mathscr F)$ to $(E,\mathscr E)$, then
$$K: \mathcal{B}(\mathscr E) \to \mathcal B(\mathscr F),\quad K f(x)=K(x,f)=\int_E f(y) k(x,dy)$$
defines a bounded linear map (from bounded measurable to bounded measurable functions) with
$$ (f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathscr E)^+ \uparrow f \in \mathcal{B}(\mathscr E) \Rightarrow K f_n \uparrow K f.$$
**Claim: Conversely every bounded linear positive map $ \mathcal{B}(\mathscr E) \to \mathcal B(\mathscr F)$ that satisfies the above condition is given by a kernel**

How do you go about showing something like this? Is it some Banach algebra characterisation theorem? We can define the composition of kernels as
If $k$ is a kernel from $(F,\mathscr F)$ to $(E,\mathscr E)$ and $l$ is a kernel from $(G,\mathscr G)$ to $(F,\mathscr F)$, then the composition of $k$ and $l$ is a kernel $l\star k$ from $(G,\mathscr G)$ to $(E,\mathscr E)$ defined by
$$l\star k (x,A)=\int_F k(y,A) l(x,dy)$$
for $x\in G$ and $A \in \mathscr E$.
On the bounded kernels with the sup norm we get a submultiplicative norm. I'm guessing this is a Banach algebra with
$$L\star K f(x)=\int_F f(y) l\star k(x, dy)=\int_F f(y) \int_F k(z,dy)l(x,dz)$$
But I'm not sure this is the right way to define the composition operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in F$ and $A\in\mathscr{E}$ let $k(x,A)=K1_A(x)$. Since $K1_A$ is measurable by assumption, it suffices to check that $A\mapsto k(x,A)$ is a measure for every $x\in F$. For that purpose let $(A_n)$ be a disjoint sequence in $\mathscr{E}$ and $f_n=1_{\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k}=\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{A_k}$. Then $f_n\nearrow 1_{\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k}$, hence
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k(x,A_k)=Kf_n(x)\nearrow K1_{\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k}(x)=k\left(x,\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right).
$$
Note that the space you constructed is not a Banach algebra because you cannot multiply arbitrary elements. In any case, even if $(E,\mathscr{E})=(F,\mathscr{F})$, I do not see how this result should follow from an abstract representation theorem for Banach algebras.

Comment: I thought Gelfand + Riesz Markov Kakutani somehow

Comment: But producing a measure from the induced linear functional on continuous functions is non-trivial (the representation theorem you mention), while doing the same from the linear functional on bounded measurable functions is trivial. So I do not see the advantage of representing anything as a space of continuous functions.